# selecting column values where they exist from a hardcoded list

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code:

```
cluster_groups as (
select uc_id, uc_name_imported from team   
where uc_id in (876,877,878,879,880))
```

The problem is that even though I have specified the list of uc_id
in the where clause, I want to only select a value from it IF it exists in the
uc_id column in the team table.

Comment: `in` will return only rows that exist, so the problem statement is unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and explain how the result you're actually getting differs from the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments). You should also update your question and show the _complete_ query you are using.

Comment: My question has been answered by @Mureinik above!